# Database table names with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I already have a database named "mydb", where I have a table called "AERODROME".

My models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Aerodrome(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)
```

And I have this method at views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from helloworld.models import Aerodrome

def aerodromes(request):
    return render(request, 'aerodromes.html', {'aerodromes': Aerodrome.objects.all()})
```

At my templates folder, I have aerodromes.html, which is quite simple too:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        {% for aerodrome in aerodromes %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ aerodrome.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ aerodrome.Longitude }}</td>
                <td>{{ aerodrome.Latitude }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I test through my browser, I get an error, because it looks like it's accessing the table with a wrong name. My application is called "helloworld" since it's a test, and instead of accessing to mydb.AERODROMES, it is accessing to mydb.helloworld_aerodrome (Also note the case sensitive problem).

Since I already had the database populated, I haven't run syncdb (I understood it wasn't neccessary, but maybe this is the problem).

So, the problem is that I don't know why it is adding "helloworld_" to the table name, and also that I still don't know for sure where exactly am I fixing the table name (and from there comes the case sensitive problem having "aerodrome" and not "AERODROMES").

Any help here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the `Meta` class ([documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/)) inside your `models.py` model definition:

```
class Aerodrome(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AERODROMES'
```

This will override the default naming scheme for model tables in the SQL database.

---

You can also add the `managed` attribute to control whether or not `python manage.py syncdb` and `python manage.py flush` manage the table.

```
class Aerodrome(models.Model):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AERODROMES'
        managed = False
```

With this you can `syncdb` without fear of wiping your data.

Comment: Does managed imply only that the table was externaly populated, or would it also imply that it is not possible to write into that table from the application?

Comment: Invoking `Aerodrome.save()` will work as expected provided the database table actually jives with the model definition (e.g. has the correct schema to match your `Name`, `Latitude`, and `Longitude`).

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed):

_"If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model. ... This is the only difference when managed=False. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal."_

Answer (score 4):

from the django docs:
It is **strongly advised** that you use **lowercase** table names when you override the table name via db_table, particularly if you are using the MySQL backend. See the MySQL notes for more details.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#table-names

Answer (score 1):

Specifying table name for your model explicitly should help:

```
from django.db import models

class Aerodrome(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AERODROMES'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [db table name in models `Meta` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/). as

```
class Aerodrome(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    Latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)
    Longitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=7)

    class Meta:
        db_table="AERODROMES"
```

If you are prepopulating table externally. take care the data is appropriate/compatible in each record/field.

However, you have to `syncdb` as other tables required for django are created.